# XML to PDF | iText | java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xml-parsing, itext

I've tried different "input.xml" and "tagMap.xml" files.
Tweaking around with the structure and tags... But i keep getting the "MalformedURLException"

Any suggestions, other than solving this with iText, are welcome. As long as the input files are always a XML with content (input.xml) and another XML with the tagMap (tagMap.xml).

This problem comes from the need to upgrade our systems. Weblogic server 8 to 12c, Java 1.4 to 1.8... There's no intent to change any functionality on the application, the code/libraries just seem to be incompatible.

(Note: I've reduced all the java code + content/structure of the "input.xml" and "tagMap.xml" for demonstration purposes.)

Any ideas?

```
    package sandbox;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import com.lowagie.text.*;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
    import com.lowagie.text.xml.XmlParser;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String testPath = "D:"+File.separator+"JavaTest";
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
          Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
     try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream
                      (testPath+File.separator+"outPut.pdf"));
    // step 3: we parse the document
          XmlParser.parse(document, testPath+ File.separator+ "input.xml"
                  , testPath+ File.separator+ "tagMap.xml");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: java.net.MalformedURLException
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:620)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at com.lowagie.text.xml.TagMap.init(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.xml.TagMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.xml.XmlParser.go(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.xml.XmlParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at sandbox.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:532)
... 15 more
```

input.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<GREETING>
    <TEXT>Hello World PDF Test</TEXT>
</GREETING>
```

tagMap.xml content:

```
<tagmap>
<tag name="iText" alias="GREETING" />
<tag name="paragraph" alias="TEXT">
    <attribute name="leading" value="14" />
    <attribute name="size" value="10" />
    <attribute name="style" value="italic" />
    <attribute name="align" value="left" />
</tag>
</tagmap>
```

Using:
[com.lowagie.text.xml.XmlParser](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/xml/XmlParser.html#parse(com.lowagie.text.DocListener,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
public static void parse(DocListener document,
                     java.lang.String file,
                     java.lang.String tagmap)
Parses a given file that validates with the iText DTD and writes the content to a document.
Parameters:
    document - The document that will listen to the parser
    file - The path to a file with the content
    tagmap - A user defined tagmap
```

Comment: `com.lowagie`? You are using an iText version that is over a decade old! Please reproduce your problem in the most recent version (7.1.4) and then ask your question again (edit this one).

Comment: Well... yes I've notice that and also that the version 2.1.7 is the last one under MPL/LGPL all newer verisons ("com.itextpdf" packages) are payed versions under  AGPL. I was looking for a free option if possible... Even if its not with iText. We are upgrading the systems (server, OS version, java version..) and the ideal solution would be the one with less impact as we are not changing any functionality of the app.

Comment: "Paid versions under AGPL" is a *contradictio in terminis*. You have the choice between a free version under AGPL and a paid version under commercial license. Depending on your use case, you may be able to use the AGPL version for free. Are you using iText in an internal application, or are outside people using your application?

Comment: It´s a internal Corporate application. Only our employees have access to it. So i can use any version of i text?... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Chances are very high that you can use any version of iText. Contact iText Software to make sure, do not rely on the personal opinion of one random person on the internet (even if that person is in iText employee).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an actual solution for my question but if anyone comes here looking for one I state what I did:
What I did was to remove all usage of iText libs and replace the PDF processing with apache FOP 2.3
The implementation was straight forward. I had to generate the .xsl (template) and .xml (containing the input variables).